# Not able to fetch more than 500 records using RESTful Web services using ADF REST API

Tags: rest, oracle-adf

I have a get request which fetches only the first 500 records every time. When I give offset=500, I don't get any records though there are more than 500 records in table. As per my understanding, the purpose of offset is to give the starting point and limit gives the total number of records required. Why am I able to fetch only the first 500 records and what can I do to solve this
Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have set a row limit in the view object used by the REST API or may have a **Row Fetch Limit** property set in your **adf-config.xml** file.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-view-object-tuning.htm#BCGHDDAD